# i am using jcarousel with the shortcodes ultimate wordpress plugin and i am having trouble posting it on the front page

Tags: plugins, jcarousel, shortcode

I took the code from this page http://signsanddesigns2go.com/?page_id=608 and it works but I want it on my home page so I went to the editor and tried to copy and past the code under the banner slider it showed up but the images did not rotate can anyone help me with this issue please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the auto attribute?

```
.jcarousel({
  auto:2,
  scroll:1,
  wrap:"last"
})
```